# What does the Ethereum registry entry confirming token ownership look like?

Tags: tokens, nft, bytecode

I have read that data about token owners such as NFT on Ethereum is stored in smart contracts. However, I have not found any example anywhere of how this looks in practice. What I mean is how does the entry for the contract owner look like? For example, in the case of databases on a central server, it could be some table with columns and rows where I can find an entry indicating at least the asset identifier and owner. How does this look in the case of Ethereum? Can someone maybe show an existing token and a database entry that states who is the owner?

Comment: Sry, but we can’t explain the blockchain & smart contract here :) just for simplicity it is key value storage , to change the value u need to send and sign a transaction. some parts of storage are controlled by roles or contract code and this code check if u allowed to change the value. In NFT u have smart contracts which control the storage and it has a Mapping from NFT ID to Owner

Comment: Do you mean in the context of the entire Ethereum blockchain? or in the context of an individual token contract? In both cases, it's just a simple key-value store, the key being the address or public-key.

Comment: In the context of an individual token. I understand idea of smart contract which is just a kind of computer program. But if you talk about token, what do you mean? Is it the computer program with extra line of code that points to the owner, so the owner is just owner of smart contract also? From smart contract perspective where is this information about owner? What is the result from mining / executing transfer command in program? For example, in relational databases if i want someone to be owner of virtual item in game i can just simple create a new row in table that will indicate userID and

Comment: @Mr.X NFT usually have a mapping from tokenId to owner address. This is not part of the [EIP 721](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) specification, so a contract is free to implement it another way, or to not implement it.